# CPU does not support AVX instruction set

Tags: cpu

I just bought myself the Logitech Brio. in order to put the background changing options to use I tried to download ChromaCam’s software. When I tried to install it, I get a message that my CPU does not support the AVX instruction set.

I'm running Intel core 2 Duo T7250 @2.0 GHZ   64-bit os X64 base processor. Besides getting new hardware, what can I do to get around this problem? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: If it requires AVX and you lack it then there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 4):

#### I tried to install Chromacam, I get a message that my CPU does not support AVX

The Intel core 2 Duo T7250 chip does not support AVX.

You can either:

1. Replace your CPU or
2. Use some other software (not Chromacam) that doesn't require ATX to configure your Logitech Brio background options.

Comment: Thanks thats the cold fact I knew but had my fingers crossed. As far as i know its the only software that is available.  Logitech offers the download and nothing else that i have found so far. why have a piece of hardware that is top of the line.Jjust to  handicap it to using something that is not widely used ? makes no sense to me. But Who em I to say ?

Comment: @RussellMatthews Almost every processor (except budget lines) since 2011/2012 has it, what makes you believe it is "not widely used"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#CPUs_with_AVX

Comment: a Core2Duo T7250 is from fall of '07. https://ark.intel.com/products/31728/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T7250-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB